# Visual Basic - Selecting values from a string and defining them as something

Tags: vb.net

I have a log file in txt, inside are strings of information. one string looks like this:

49000 120614 12334480 12 32 2 90 90 90 321 384 2 345 873 890

each value between the spaces represents something in specific, (e.g the second line "120614" is the date "12 June 2014") I am writing a program where I load the txt file into it, and then when i click a certain button it will take this string and put all the values into a specific text box, for instance, "Date = 12 06 2014". I have been researching how to find a certain line and declare that line with its contents as something, but I have not found the answer!! I  am using Visual Basic to write it, and I really need help with what direction to take, will stramreader be able to do this?? What function am I looking for?

Here is my code for loading the file.. Just incase.

```
  Public Class Form1

  Private Sub browsebtn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles browsebtn1.Click
    Dim filedialog As New OpenFileDialog 'openfiledialog1 is now filedialog'
    filedialog.Filter = "Text Document|*.txt" 'filter the openfiledialogs file extension to txt only'
    filedialog.Title = "Select Bosvark Log File.." 'openfiledialog title'
    If filedialog.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then 'if the file is chosen then..'
        filepath1.Text = filedialog.FileName 'filepath1 text is file path of selected file'
        RichTextBox1.LoadFile(filepath1.Text, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText) 'richtextbox1 retrieves the file path and displays the document'
    End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub convertbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles convertbtn.Click
    If RichTextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please load a file first!") 'If user doesnt load a file, give them an error message.'
    End If
     End Sub

    Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles     RichTextBox1.TextChanged
    If RichTextBox1.Text = "" Then
        RichTextBox1.Visible = False 'If there is no file loaded, The textbox will not appear.'
        Else
            RichTextBox1.Visible = True 'if the file is loaded, textbox will appear.'
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

you can load the contents of the file to a string variable (if the file isnt too large)

```
Dim intFile As Integer
Dim strFile As String
Dim strData As String
intFile = FreeFile
strFile = "c:\temp\file.txt"
Open strFile For Input As #intFile
  strData = Input(LOF(intFile), #intFile)
Close #intFile
```

you can split all the data into an array per line

```
Dim strLine() As String
strLine = Split(strData)
```

you can loop over all lines to perform some action on all lines

```
Dim lngLine As Long
For lngLine = 0 To UBound(strLine)
  'do action
Next lngLine
```

or just perform an action on one specific line:

```
dim strField() as String
'split line into array separated per spaces
strField = Split(strLine(lngLine), " ")
```

Comment: All i needed was some sort of reference, so your answer was more than helpful.